# Web server on remote, is it possible to ssh to remote and have local browser connect to server?

Tags: linux, ssh, web-server, ssh-tunnel, localhost

On a headless remote machine which I connect to via ssh and do not have sudo privileges, I have an interactive python script with a console interface.

I want to use a simple web framework like flask or bottle to create a locally hosted web interface for that script instead.

Is it possible to connect to the machine over ssh and open a browser on my local machine to use the web interface being ran on the remote server?

---

Alternatively, if the above is not feasible -- what would be the simplest way to implement a GUI wrapper program that connects to the remote machine via ssh, runs the console interfaced python script, and controls IO to and from the script.

I have the outline of the above using PySimpleGui and expanding on the answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python. But would prefer a web interface.

*I also do not have access to read /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the remote.

Comment: Your are looking for the [-L option to ssh](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#L_3), which allows you to forward local ports to a remote destination.